Generating tokens with custom claims by adding custom parameters to the token request
Is there any way to add custom parameters to a token request body?
The current implementation we have is to make a request with one custom parameter (using a workaround):
A OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager is used, with a custom ClientCredentialsOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider which is configured with a DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient configured with a custom OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequestEntityConverter, which currently adds customParameter1 to the parameters because customParameter1 is being set as the Client Registration ID, it's therefore ultimately available via clientCredentialsGrantRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId()
Q1: why does this use a OAuth2AuthorizeRequest but the entity mapper work with a OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequest, without any details from the original request object?
Investigation
Converters
A customer entity converter has to implement the following:
  @Override
  protected MultiValueMap<String, String> createParameters(
      OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequest clientCredentialsGrantRequest) {

The OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequest only allows to get a ClientRegistration and AuthorizationGrantType.
But I need to add in an additional k/v parameter in some cases. This will be used by the oauth provider to add it as a claim to the token. But seems no way to allow that. And it would be good to use the framework.
Attributes
To get the token, the oauthClientManager.authorize() method is called with an OAuth2AuthorizeRequest object, in it you can add attributes.
I've seen it possible to override some parts of the clientManager, including entityConverter but also contextMapper yet that does not seem useful.
I originally thought that the attributes would available in the entity converter and would have been voila, but that is obviously not the case.
There seems lots of ways to configure converters (i.e. addParametersConverter of AbstractOAuth2AuthorizationGrantRequestEntityConverter and mappers, but none of them actually providing any useful extension or means to provide the data to be used by them.
